# How to translate responses from server in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, translation

I have a service in my application to create users. When user tries to create account and makes some mistakes backend returns errors. I need to translate these errors into another language. This is the only place where I need translation in the application. What's the best way to do this?

**user.service.ts**

```
export class UserService {
  apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  public errors$: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  createUser(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/v1/auth/users/`, user).pipe(
    catchError((error) => {
      const errorMessage: string[] = Object.values(error.error);
      this.errors$.next(errorMessage[0]);

      return throwError(error);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

**registration.component.html**

```
... some blocks

<div class="validation" *ngIf="userService.errors$ | async as errors">
  <small *ngFor="let error of errors">{{ error }}</small>
</div>
```

Comment: The best way? Have it be returned translated from your API. Other than that, if you only need it once, translate the errors inside of `catchError()` or use https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

Comment: If you want an ugly solution just create an object with all the possible returned errors and translate each of those in userService. ngx-translate is a large module and if you are 100% sure it wouldn't be used beyond this one time it might be an overkill